# Compact complex manifold with non-spin universal cover

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold (or more specifically assume $M$ is a Kaehler manifold) and $\pi: \widetilde{M}\to M$ be the universal cover. What restrictions does the condition "$\widetilde{M}$ is not spin" put on $M$?

Comment: Not much. There are plenty of simply connected projective manifolds which are not spin.